# Yield statement cannot be used inside anonymous method

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, anonymous-types, yield

I'm using the following code which works:

```
    IEnumerable<Tag> CreateTags()
    {
        var suppliers = SupplierQuery.MatchTerms(Min, Max);

        foreach (var item in suppliers)
        {
            var text = item.Name;
            var route = PageRoute.GetSupplierRoute(item.Name);

            yield return new Tag(text, route);
        }
    }
```

I've been trying to chain these 2 statments together using a IEnumerable.ForEach extension method, like this:

```
    IEnumerable<Tag> CreateTags()
    {
        var suppliers = SupplierQuery.MatchTerms(Min, Max)
            .ForEach(x =>
            {
                yield return new Tag(x.Name, PageRoute.GetSupplierRoute(x.Name));

            });
    }
```

However, I get an error - "Yield statement cannot be used inside an anonymous method" - is there any way round this without creating a new `List<Tag>` or must they be kept separate?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no `IEnumerable.ForEach` extension method. You either have a custom extension method that you wrote, or you mean `List<T>.ForEach`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you insist on using `yield return` you must use a separate method. In general I'd recommend trying to make due with the existing query operators first. `CreateTags` can easily be expressed with `Select`.

In any case `ForEach` is not equipped to receive a return value from the function that you pass. I think you meant `Select`.

```
return SupplierQuery.MatchTerms(Min, Max)
       .Select(x => new Tag(x.Name, PageRoute.GetSupplierRoute(x.Name)));
```

I think that's all you need.